# Pulseaudio with locked channels don't work so well with media keys

Tags: pulseaudio, xfce

I got pulseaudio set to lock left and right channel together on the output device, but if I change volume with my media keys rapidly, the channels go out of sync, leaving one louder than the other. Is there another way I can force the channels to always be at the same volume?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this would work, but maybe you could try assigning a keyboard shortcut to those same keys to change the volume. Below the first command lowers the volume 5%, the second one increases it 5%, and the third one toggles the mute button.

```
amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%-

amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+

amixer -D pulse sset Master toggle
```

Comment: This is how I currently do the volume changes, and they go out of sync regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script I wrote to do this :

```
#!/bin/bash

vol=$( amixer -D pulse get Master | grep "Front Left:" | cut -d[ -f2 | cut -d% -f1)

#read argument
if test $# -ge 1 && let $1
then
    incr=$1
else
    incr="3"
    echo "Incrementing sound by $incr% (default)."
fi

echo "Current volume : $vol - setting it to $(( $vol + $incr ))."

#set the sound to a flat value, and unmute it
amixer -D pulse sset Master $(( $vol + $incr ))% unmute > /dev/null
```

So instead of `amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+` , you need to call that script : paste the text above in a file (eg. `/home/yourname/volume` ).

Then you just need to make it executable (`chmod 755 /home/yourname/volume`) and you can replace your previous command with this one : `/home/yourname/volume -5` (or +5, +3, -3...).

It should do exactly the same, except it unmutes the volume if it is muted.